# How to enable javascript window.close() in vaadin dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, vaadin

I have a html page which has a Close button which on click, should close the window. This html page is being loaded on a Vaadin Dialog. I understand that Vaadin takes care of closing the dialog with window.setClosable(true). But, the button in html page also should do the same. How do I enable this ?
Below is the code :

**myHelp.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
.
.
<!-- This is at the footer right corner -->
<p class="myClass" align="right"><img src="images/iconclose.gif" width="50" height="10" border="0" onClick="window.close()" title="Close"></p>
.
.
</body>
</html>
```

**Java Code:**

```
.
.
String link = "test/myHelp.html";
MenuItem menuItem = null;
if (link.contains("/test")) {

menuItem = menuBar.addItem("", new ExternalResource(StringUtil.append("/images/", images.get(i))), new Command() {

@Override
public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {

    final Window window = new Window(this.caption);
    window.setClosable(true);
    window.setWindowMode(WindowMode.NORMAL);
    window.setModal(true);
    window.setDraggable(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.center();
    window.addStyleName("abcdailog");
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setSizeFull();
    layout.setSpacing(true);
    layout.setMargin(true);

    if (!CommonUtil.isEmpty(this.styleName)) {
        window.addStyleName("abcStyle");
        layout.setMargin(false);
    }
    if (!CommonUtil.isEmpty(link)) {
        BrowserFrame browser = new BrowserFrame(null, new ExternalResource(this.link));
        browser.setSizeFull();
        layout.addComponent(browser);
    } else {
        verticalLayout.setSizeFull();
        layout.addComponent(verticalLayout);
    }

    window.setContent(layout);
    UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
    }
    }
    });
.
.
.
```

What happens is myHtml gets loaded in the new window. As a vaadin window, everything is fine but since the html has a window.close on an image, which is suppose to work is not working. I hope the code helps in better understanding.

Comment: Just to make your life simpler, could you not add a close button somewhere at the bottom of the Vaadin window instead of having it in the HTML content?

Comment: I guess that is not possible here. Is there a way I can make my HTML work with Vaadin ?

Comment: You did not show any code so far, but are you able to assign a function to `onClick`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest one would be to add a Vaadin button say at the bottom of the window. However if that's not a choice, there are a few ways of doing this, the first one which comes to mind (and possibly the next simplest one) is adding [a callback JS function](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-javascript.html#advanced.javascript.callback) to close the window.

**1) Custom window implementation:**

```
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.label.ContentMode;
import com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;

    public class MyHtmlWindow extends Window {
    private static final String CLOSE_WINDOW_FUNCTION = "closeWindow";

    public MyHtmlWindow() {
        // some window configuration
        setModal(true);
        setClosable(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public void show(UI ui) {
        // add some HTML content in a label including the call to the closeWindow() JS function
        setContent(new Label("<html>\n" +
                "<button type=\"button\" onClick=\"" + CLOSE_WINDOW_FUNCTION + "();\">Close</button>\n" +
                "<script>\n", ContentMode.HTML));

        // add a JS function to close the window
        JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction(CLOSE_WINDOW_FUNCTION, arguments -> this.close());

        // show the window
        ui.addWindow(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // call super so everything gets cleaned up nicely
        super.close();
        // remove previously added function
        JavaScript.getCurrent().removeFunction(CLOSE_WINDOW_FUNCTION);
    }
}
```

**2) Usage:**

```
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        new MyHtmlWindow().show(this);
    }
}
```

**3) Result:**

[image: JS Callback window]

**P.S.:** Suggestions for improvements are welcome

Comment: Close in the html page is at the footer with some user defined class. Now, including all that is also important if I have to maintain uniformity. How can I achieve that.

Comment: @nam While the above may make sense to you, it makes little to none for us without some context. Please share some code and add the relevant explanations so we can understand what the problem is. Furthermore, since this sounds like a separate problem, please try to open a new question if it's difficult to modify the current one without altering its initial scope.

Comment: I have added the code. Please check and let me know if there is a solution to this.

Comment: @nam `html has a window.close on an image` that will not work. In short, the window object is created on the server side, so the client side (java script) has no knowledge of it. If you read [the docs I suggested](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-javascript.html#advanced.javascript.callback), you will see that you can add that JS callback function as I did in the code above. This will allow you to make a call from the client side to the server side and close that window. Take a look at the sample above and let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: In the above solution close button is created from vaadin. Solution is fine. But while trying, I found that `javascript:fn_windowClose()` which does `window.parent.location.reload();` works. As per my understanding, on a vaadin window, the javascript which is on my client shouldn't have worked at all then how is this working ?

Comment: @nam In the sample, the button is created in an HTML snippet, and it's not a Vaadin button. You can adapt the solution to your scenario where you load the HTML file, keeping the idea is the same: the HTML button needs to call a **known** JS callback function, which will be added when opening the window, and removed when closing it. Regarding the `window.parent.location.reload();`, this simply [reloads your document](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp), it's basically a refresh. If you annotate your UI with `@PreserveOnRefresh` I bet it won't work any longer...